# "self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem" Not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, viewdidload, rightbarbuttonitem

I have the following code taken straight from the NavBar sample code from Apple.  I put this in the viewDidLoad method for a view in my app that is being presented modally, and it wont work.

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AddTitle", @"")
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(addAction:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you having navigation bar there? most of the time in presentModalViewController method viewController does not take navigationController.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use something other than a Navigation Bar to in order to present a bar at the top of the modal view in order to present the "Add" button?

Comment: Yeah actually presentModalViewController does what it says, presents a viewController modally, not a nagivationController, in that case you should use pushViewController:animated: or put your viewController into another navigationController and present that nav as the modal viewController ... OR (didn't try) change the navigationController modalTransitionStyle for the one you want (again, didn't try myself so I don't know if it works)

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO; put this statement in first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use these lines of code on the page where you present the other view.

```
sceondController *obj=[[[sceondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sceondController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        UINavigationController *navController=[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj] autorelease];

        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

and in second view use same code which you are using for making navigation button.

May be it resolves your problem.

Comment: From what little I know(I am a noob), I know you are right, but placing this code in the firstController has caused the view to stop showing up at all.

Comment: You need to give your class name and nib name at place of sceondController and nib Name here initWithNibName:@"nib Name"

Answer (score 2):

Okay explained solution:

presentModalViewController:animated: presents a viewController modally, which does not have a `UINavigationBar`, so you can do some things:

1. Add a `UINavigationBar` in your viewController's nib and add the "Add" button there and everything you need to setup.
2. You can use `pushViewController:animated`: to show the viewController modally which will be on the navigation stack and have the `UINavigationBar` for you to add your button
3. If your first viewController is not a `UINavigationController`, using `pushViewController:animated:` won't solve it, so you can present a `UINavigationController` modally with your viewController as the rootViewController:

```cs
 YourViewController *viewController =[[[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Hope any of this helps

Answer (score 0):

I assume your view controller is actually a UINavigationController and everything else is in place. In which case I would change two things.

1. I wouldn't autorelease the UIBarButtonItem. That tends to be unreliable with view controllers so add the button to your list of things to dealloc at cleanup
2. I would use the setter function to set the button. Here is my code that works in my navigation controller

   clearAllButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear All" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightButtonPressed:)];

   [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:clearAllButton];

Comment: 1) Fair Enough. 2)How do you get a modal view to show up in the first place? Maybe my problem is a step further back.

Comment: Sounds like it is. Your comment also belongs above this answer. I think it flows with the advice from - herz. Which I agree with btw. That is, if you want to present modally. Personally, I've published tons of apps and never found a need for a modal view controller.

Comment: Setting an autorelease object with a setter method does a retain, so the autorelease UIBarButtonItem is okay; also, what you do with your setter method does the same thing as the "self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem"

Answer (score -1):

Run your app in real device. In iOS6 it is not working on simulator.